# Get event of Home button

Tags: android

My requirement is that when user clicks the home button at any screen in application, he is redirected to device home screen and when he comes back to the application he will redirect to app home screen rather than at screen where he pressed the home button.

Any help would be appreciaed.

Comment: Setting android:noHistory="true" on the activity in your manifest will remove an activity from the stack whenever it is navigated away from

Comment: you can set    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" in your manifest file for particular activity also will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you can use to detect Home-Button pushes and call appropriate functions.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or

In android manifest do setting `android:noHistory="true"` on the activity,this will remove an activity from the stack whenever it is not there in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you want to go Home Screen when you press Home button from any Screen. So you better take a `BaseActivity` extending `Activity` and inside that override `onKeyDown()` as below.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
            // Implement starting Home Activity with Clear Top
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Then Extend all your activities with `BaseActivity` instead of Activity. So that Every Activity get onKeyDown() Functionality so that any where you press Home Button it navigates back to HomeScreen with removing all Activities.